# wlan0: carrier lost with specific router

Tags: wpa

so I've setup my Raspberry Pi Zero W with latest Raspbian img. Whenever I tried to connect it to the main router the syslog always says:

```
Feb 17 23:20:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[252]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Feb 17 23:20:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[252]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Feb 17 23:20:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[252]: DUID 00:01:00:01:23:4f:5c:ba:b8:27:eb:ce:72:2a
Feb 17 23:20:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[252]: wlan0: IAID eb:ce:72:2a
Feb 17 23:20:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[252]: wlan0: adding address fe80::2e45:eacb:2a5b:a805
Feb 17 23:20:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[252]: wlan0: carrier lost
Feb 17 23:20:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[252]: wlan0: deleting address fe80::2e45:eacb:2a5b:a805
Feb 17 23:21:03 raspberrypi dhcpcd[252]: timed out
Feb 17 23:21:03 raspberrypi dhcpcd[252]: forked to background, child pid 358
```

My `wpa_supplicant.conf` file looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="my_ssid"
    psk="my_pw"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

When I change the network config to connect to another router or hotspot everything is fine, but not with the router provided by my ISP which it seems to be a "[MitraStar GPT-2541GNAC](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/MitraStar_GPT-2541GNAC)".

Thanks

Comment: What is the distance between the RasPi and the failing router?

Comment: @Ingo 0.5 m or 19.685 Inch through a wall.

Comment: Not a big distance - shouldn't be the problem ...

Comment: Did you tried running wpa_supplicant with debug output as suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good so far with your setup. It is obvious that the problem is the router. You may have a double check at your routers settings or you can try to start `wpa_supplicant` with debug output. You will get a bunch of output but maybe you will see what could be the problem. First you have to stop a running `wpa_supplicant`. I don't know anything about your setup but brute force is to `sudo killall wpa_supplicant`. Maybe you will lose a ssh connection? Anyway, the command to start wpa_supplicant with debug option `-d` is:

```
rpi ~$ sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -d -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0
```

Comment: Could you elaborate just a bit on what physical manifestation is checked/measured to determine the presence or absence of "carrier"? In other words, how does the system decide whether the carrier is present or not?

Comment: @Seamus Sorry, don't know how this is done. I trust the hardware and firmware doing it. To understand this in more details you should have to look at the source code.

Comment: No worries - it was just curiosity. I'd have to guess that it's a different measure for WiFi than it is for Ethernet. The source code is a good idea, but I'm a.) not sure where to start, and b.) probably don't want to know badly enough! :)